# detect and change website encoding in python

Tags: python, encoding, beautifulsoup, scrape

I have a problem with website encoding. I maked a program to scrape a website but i didn't have successfully with changing encoding of readed content. My code is:

```
import sys,os,glob,re,datetime,optparse
import urllib2

from BSXPath import BSXPathEvaluator,XPathResult
#import BeautifulSoup

#from utility import *

sTargetEncoding = "utf-8"

page_to_process = "http://www.xxxx.com" 
req = urllib2.urlopen(page_to_process)
content = req.read()
encoding=req.headers['content-type'].split('charset=')[-1]
print encoding

ucontent = unicode(content, encoding).encode(sTargetEncoding)
#ucontent = content.decode(encoding).encode(sTargetEncoding)
#ucontent = content

document = BSXPathEvaluator(ucontent)

print "ORIGINAL ENCODING: " + document.originalEncoding
```

I used external library (BSXPath an extension of BeautifulSoap) and the document.originalEncoding print the encoding of website and not the utf-8 encoding that I tried to change.
Have anyone some suggestion?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is no guarantee that the encoding presented by the HTTP headers is the same the some specified inside the HTML itself. This can happen either due to misconfiguration on the server side or the charset definition inside the HTML can be just wrong. There is really no automatic way to detect the encoding or to detect the *right* encoding. I suggest to check HTML manually for the right encoding (e.g. iso-8859-1 vs. utf-8 can be easily detected) and then hardcode the encoding somehow manually inside your app.